# Problem when trying to use (getResponseCode())

Tags: javascript, java, json, httpconnection

I have a problem in my code, I'm programming for a platform called FLUIG, in this context I need to make a call to an endpoint, but when I try to use the `getResponseCode()` method my code dies.

```
var apiC = new java.net.URL(strUrl); 
    var consumo = apiC.openConnection(); 
    responseGET = strUrl;
    
    
    //consumo.setDoOutput(!0); 
    consumo.setConnectTimeout(18e4); 
    consumo.setReadTimeout(18e4); 
    consumo.setRequestMethod("GET"); 
    consumo.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + Token); 
    consumo.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json"); 
    consumo.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json"); 
    consumo.setRequestProperty("tenant", l); 
    var intResponseCodeGET = consumo.getResponseCode();
    consumo.setDoOutput(true);
    
    
    
    //new  
    var intResponseCodeGET = ""
        intResponseCodeGET = (consumo.getResponseCode()).toString();
    
    responseGET = intResponseCodeGET;
    if( intResponseCodeGET == "200" || intResponseCodeGET == "201" )
    {   
        responseGET = "ok";
    }
```

I would like to know why and how to fix this problem

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java.  What is the benefit of converting the numeric response code to a String?

Comment: Don't use == for comparing Strings. Use the equals method. See [Comparing Strings in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-compare-strings)

Comment: I understand, I will change this, but my problem is: 'intResponseCodeGET' I did not receive the response code.